# How do I prevent textContent from overwriting the dynamically created span?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I'm trying to insert an element into the list but the span keeps getting overwritten by the textcontent that I'm giving to li. This is what the code is supposed to look like:

```
<li class="togglable"><span class="plus-sgn">+</span> Add Task</li>
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
<li class="togglable">Add Task</li>
```

And here's the code:

```
  const togglable = document.createElement('li');
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  togglable.className = 'togglable';
  span.className = 'plus-sgn';
  span.textContent = '+';
  togglable.appendChild(span);
  togglable.textContent = 'Add Task';
  taskList.appendChild(togglable);
```

Comment: Remember [not to post pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask). Post the text itself. Also: yes, that's precisely what `textContent` and `innerHTML` assignment are supposed to do: they _replace_ whatever is there with the content you give. In this case, you want `+=` instead of `=` for that innerHTML instruction so that you concatenate the string instead of assigning a new one.

Comment: You forgot to append the span.

Comment: Is there another way to make that same 'li' ?

Comment: Okay that worked!! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

To create text node use [document.createTextNode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp):

```js
function add() {
  const togglable = document.createElement('li');
  togglable.className = 'togglable';

  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.className = 'plus-sgn';
  span.textContent = '+';
  togglable.appendChild(span);

  //append text as text node
  togglable.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Add Task'));

  taskList.appendChild(togglable);
}

add();
add();
add();
```

```html
<ul id='taskList'>
  <li>Abc</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add it as follow:

```js
const taskList = document.querySelector('ul#taskList');
const togglable = `<li class="togglable"><span class="plus-sgn">+</span> Add Task</li>`;

taskList.innerHTML += togglable;
```

```html
<ul id="taskList"></ul>
```