# Why my button is not showing inside li tag?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I would to add a button (deleteButton) inside a `<li></li>` created and appended before to the `<ol>`

My code:

```js
let eventList = [];
const inputBox = document.querySelector('.input-field');
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
const itemsList = document.querySelector('.list')

function addEvent() {
  const showEvent = inputBox.value;

  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  itemsList.appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(deleteButton);


  eventList.push(showEvent)
  li.textContent = showEvent;
  inputBox.value = '';
}

submit.addEventListener('click', addEvent);
```

```html
<h1>TO-DO LIST</h1>
<input class="input-field" type="text">
<button class="submit" type="button">ADD TO-DO</button>
<ol class="list"></ol>
```

The button is not showing at all. What can I do to make it show inside the li element?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably using StackOverflow's built-in code snippet tool.

Comment: Don't use `textContent`, use `document.createTextNode` like the following: `li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(showEvent));` This has already been addressed in an existing post: [how-do-i-prevent-textcontent-from-overwriting-the-dynamically-created-span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70881625/how-do-i-prevent-textcontent-from-overwriting-the-dynamically-created-span) Using `textContent` overwrites the button.

Comment: because this line `li.textContent = showEvent;` set the entire content of your `<li>` element, and eraze any previous contnent, which is the added `<button>` delete. Just chenging your order wil be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you initialize you stuff, then append stuff later.

Your main issue is this:

```js
li.appendChild(deleteButton);
li.textContent = showEvent;
```

You are appending the button, then immediately setting the `textContent` which is overwriting the button you just added.

```js
li.textContent = showEvent;
li.appendChild(deleteButton);
```

Just make sure to set any text, prior to appending to the same element.

Also, don't forget to handle deletion from not only your DOM, but the `eventList` array.

```js
const
  eventList = [],
  inputBox = document.querySelector('.input-field'),
  submit = document.querySelector('.submit'),
  itemsList = document.querySelector('.list');

function addEvent() {
  const
    showEvent = inputBox.value.trim(),
    li = document.createElement('li'),
    deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

  li.textContent = showEvent;
  deleteButton.innerText = 'Delete';
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', removeEvent); // Add handler

  // Now append everything
  li.appendChild(deleteButton);
  itemsList.appendChild(li);
  eventList.push(showEvent);

  inputBox.value = '';
}

function removeEvent(e) {
  const
    item = e.target.closest('li'),
    index = childIndex(item); // handle duplicate todos
  item.remove();
  eventList.splice(index, 1);
};

function childIndex(element) {
  return [...element.parentNode.children].indexOf(element);
}

submit.addEventListener('click', addEvent);
```

```css
li button { margin-left: 1rem; }
```

```html
<h1>TO-DO LIST</h1>
<input class="input-field" type="text">
<button class="submit" type="button">ADD TO-DO</button>
<ol class="list"></ol>
```